# Prove that if A is diagonalizable then so is A+kI for any scalars k

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i just need help getting started, I'm not sure what tools to use..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: suppose $A$ is diagonalizable. Then there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1} = D$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. Now compute $P(A+kI)P^{-1}$ for any scalar $k$.

Comment: $P(A+kI)P^{-1}=PAP^{-1}+P(kI)P^{-1}=D+kI=diag(a_1+k,a_2+k,\cdots,a_n+k)$, where $D=diag(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$.